# Power Query Category Grouping

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am in the process of building the below power query.

The input report is based on an extract from MYOB - after a few steps, this is what it looks like.

[image]

The end results need to be a grouping based on Category. However, I can't work out how to move the value in the Hours column against the Category "Hours:"  to align with the correct category.

> Eg. Base Hourly $359.55 and Hours = 15, Laundry Allowance $2.40 Hours
>   = 2.

This is what the output needs to be:
[image]

Also, there are some instances where the hours against the "hours:" category are displayed in the value column.

Comment: From your information it is not clear how the input and output look like (is your example table the input or the output?), and how the output is derived from the input (the logic behind it).

Comment: @MarcelBeug I have updated as best I can input and output information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, the query below returns the required result.
In the query, data (Hours) from each next record is combined with the data (Category, Value) from each current record (by adding 2 indices and joining the table with itself).
Otherwise, the query should be self explanatory.

```
let
    Source = InputTable,
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Index", "Index.1", 1, 1),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index1",{"Index.1"},#"Added Index1",{"Index"},"Next",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Next" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Next", {"Category", "Value", "Hours"}, {"Next.Category", "Next.Value", "Next.Hours"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Next",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Hours", "Index", "Index.1"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Hours", each if [Next.Category] = "Hours:" then if [Next.Hours] = null then [Next.Value] else [Next.Hours] else null, Int64.Type),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Category] <> "Hours:") and ([Value] <> null or [Hours] <> null)),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Next.Category", "Next.Value", "Next.Hours"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

Comment: Thank you MarcelBeug.. your solution works perfectly! I just had to remove one part of the filtered rows to allow the accrual value to show.